# Shopware6 document API request

Tags: php, json, api, shopware, shopware6

I am currently trying to get documents from my shopware instance through the api (*shopware.emakers.eu/api/document*), I need all the documents (all types) and for each single document I need the order informations related to it.

So, here's the body of my POST request that I am simulating on Postman :

```
{
    "associations": {
        "transactions": {
            "associations": {
                "order": {
                    "associations": {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expected this to work but for a reason that I did not understand yet, I am getting an error response that asks me to mention an orderId, documentTypeId, fileType, config, deepLinkCode. It seems that it's trying to create a new document.

Maybe I am using the wrong api endpoint ? But this endpoint works if I only make a GET request. And I don't know which endpoint I can use in case of this is not the correct one.

Any clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it is indeed the wrong endpoint. `POST /api/document` would only be correct to create a new document record.

There are two ways to fetch data of one or more records.

1. Use `GET /api/document/{id}?associations[order][]` if you have the id of a specific document record. Since it requires the `GET` method you must provide the associations as query params.
2. Use the endpoint `POST /api/search/document` to search for any documents and add the association in the request body.

```
{
    "associations": {
        "order": {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I changed the URL to /api/search/document but I only get the orderId in the relations array response (which is anyway available in the whole response, isn't possible to get the whole order data ? The plan was to avoid making different requests to get data for each document.